# jenkins scripted pipeline junit test results

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a script generated through pipeline snippet generator for my junit test results.

```
junit allowEmptyResults: true, keepLongStdio: true, testResults: 'report/nosetests.xml'
```

Can I use the same script for my jenkins scriptted pipeline as well?

Comment: I don't see why not. Have you tried it?

Comment: It’s working, thanks, the snippet generator will work for both scripted and dsl pipeline.